# Swift UISearchBar has Broken Design

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

help me...
I only do is that add UISearchbar with storyboard.
run the app,then,UISearchBar's design is broken.
what can I do with this situation..
[environment]
- swift
- xcode7.2
- Deployment Target 8.0

[image]

please help me.

Comment: I'm beginner of Xcode and Swift.

Comment: That seems like a lot more than just adding a search bar to the storyboard. Show code or a storyboard for the other controls.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than this, it's most likely that you're not setting the layout of your controls properly.